# Duality between Thom space and a manifold embedded into a sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, duality-theorems, stable-homotopy-theory

In a document https://www.math.purdue.edu/~gottlieb/Bibliography/53.pdf (s. 19) it is mentioned that there is a map $S^n \to M^+ \wedge \mathrm{Th}\left(\nu \left(M, S^n\right)\right)$, which gives a Spanier-Whitehead duality between these spaces. How can it be proven exactly?